# обновление данных в ListView

Tags: java, android

В методе onCreate заполняю listview  из БД и вешаю слушателей на элементы listview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_groups_delete);

    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper = new DataBaseOpenHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase() ; //открытие БД на запись

   //связь ListView с данными из БД

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.nameDelGroup);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);//устанавливаем режим выбора
    cursor = db.query("groups", new String[]
            {"_id", "name_group"},null, null, null, null, "name_group ASC");
    CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor, new String[]{"name_group"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1},0 );
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // слушатель элементов ListView
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            scanSelected();
        }
    });

 }
```

удаляю элементы из БД методом deleteChoose:

```
public void deleteChoose (){
    long[] cip = listView.getCheckedItemIds();
    for (int i = 0; i < cip.length; i++) {
        long aCip = cip[i];
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + aCip, null);
        }

listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();        

}
```

но при вызове listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged (); получаю nullpointerexception , вероятно из за отсутствия экземпляра объекта, но 
не могу понять почему?, он же вроде остался..

Answer (score 2):

listAdapter невидим в методе.
Всё будет хорошо, если listAdapter объявлен статичным в классе или если его передать в метод deleteChoose() параметром.

```
public void deleteChoose (CursorAdapter cursorAdapter){
    long[] cip = listView.getCheckedItemIds();
    for (int i = 0; i < cip.length; i++) {
        long aCip = cip[i];
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + aCip, null);
        }

    cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();        

}
```

Comment: static позволил сделать курсор адаптер видимым, но nullpointerexception все равно остался((

Comment: Попробуйте второй вариант - передать listAdapter в качестве параметра.
Если Вам интересно именно работать со статичным экземпляром, то необходимо убедиться, что в CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,... ) Вы не указываете класс (тип) экземпляра listAdapter.

Отмечу, что вариант с передачей параметра всё же предпочтительней в данном случае, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Напомню, что статичные поля доступны на уровне класса, а значит, при наличии множества экземпляров этого класса, нельзя гарантировать, что под listAdapter лежит нужный объект.

Comment: пробовал, но там еще хуже.. этот метод вызывается из диалог-фрагмента через интерфейс и начинает ругаться, что метод в интерфейсе без параметров.. а тянуть параметры в диалог как мне кажется не совсем корректно

Comment: Да. Интерфейсы ломать не надо.
Значит static.

А как объявлен listView, используемый в методе deleteChoose ? Простое поле класса или тоже статичное?

Comment: студия показывала одну и ту же static переменную во всех частях кода